# Jinja2-Error: "no loader for this environment specified" after include in main template

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I want to use Jinja2 to render an HTML template that should contain the same footer consisting of divs on every page. I have created my own HTML template for the footer, in which I use the @page attribute and the running property:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #footer-content {
                position: running(footer-content);
      
            @page {
                size: A4;
                @bottom-center {
                    content: element(footer-content);
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="footer-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
        
</html>
```

I include this template in my main HTML template by using the following code there:

```
{% include "footer_template.html" %}
```

As soon as I do the include and try to render the template with Jinja2 (and exporting it as a PDF using WeasyPrint), I get the error. Before I swapped out the footer, everything worked fine, but the footer was obviously not displayed on all pages as it should have been. I do so by executing the following code, where `template.html`is my main-template including the import:

```py
with open('template.html', 'r') as html_template:
            content = html_template.read()

        jinja_template = Template(content)

       
        rendered_template = jinja_template.render(....)


        with open('final.pdf', 'wb') as final_pdf:
           HTML(string=rendered_template).write_pdf(final_pdf)
```